# Liquibase load data in a format other than CSV

Tags: sql, json, liquibase

With the load data option that Liquibase provides, one can specify seed data in a CSV format. Is there a way I can provide say, a JSON or XML file with data that Liquibase would understand?

The use case is we are trying to put in some sample data which is hierarchical. E.g. Category - Subcategory relation which would require putting in parent id for all related categories. If there is a way to avoid including the ids in the seed data via say, JSON.

```
{
    "MainCat1": ["SubCat11", "SubCat12"],
    "MainCat2": ["SubCat21", "SubCat22"]
}
```

Very likely to have this as not supported (couldn't make Google help me) but is there a way to write a plugin or something that does this? Pointer to a guide (if any) would help.

NOTE: This is not about specifying the change log in that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not currently supported and supporting it robustly would be pretty difficult. The main difficultly lies in the fact that Liquibase is designed to be database-platform agnostic, combined with the design goal of being able to generate the SQL required to do an operation without actually doing the operation live.

Inserting data like you want without knowing the keys and just generating SQL that could be run later is going to be very difficult, perhaps even impossible. I would suggest approaching Nathan, who is the main developer for Liquibase, more directly. The best way to do that might be through the [JIRA bug database for Liquibase](https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE).

If you want to have a crack at implementing it, you could start by looking at the code for the `LoadDataChange` class [(source in Github)](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/LoadDataChange.java), which is where the CSV support currently lives.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Was a long shot anyway. +1 for the code pointer, will look into it but our requirement has been put on hold.